# To call different dialog window based on the button present in the component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have a component called `home` which as some description and `button` inside it. As in below image.

[image]

- I am reusing the same `home` component in another 2 components called `car` and `bike`.
- Here in `car` component on clicking the button (i,e button present in the home component), I am calling a component called `car-booking` inside a dialog window. This requirement is done now.
- But I am re-using `home` component in `bike` component too. In bike component on clicking the button(i,e button present in the home component) I should call another component `(ex bike-booking)` inside the dialog window.

How can I change the **(click)** function of the particular button on basis of its presence in the component?

The **stackblitz** [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialog-issues-pstpnj?file=app/bike-booking/bike-booking.component.html)

Comment: Could you provide your code here rather than a link.

Comment: The components are more , to post the code.so i created the `stackblitz` link Please see the `stackblitz` link. Any doubts arises i will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Output` to emit an event to the container, then in the container component you can choose what to do when you receive the event.

**HomeComponent**

```
export class HomeComponent  {

     @Output() openDialog = new EventEmitter();

     constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  open(): void {
     this.openDialog.emit();
  }

}
```

**HomeComponent's template**

```
Hai!! welcome to our application..

<div style="padding:30px;">
  <button mat-raised-button  (click)="open()" color="primary">ADD</button>
</div>
```

**BikeComponent's template**

```
<app-home (openDialog)="openDialog($event)"></app-home>
```

**BikeComponent ts**

```
export class BikeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openDialog($event: any) {
     // open desired bike component
  }

}
```

**CarComponent's template**

```
<app-home (openDialog)="openDialog($event)"></app-home>
```

**CarComponent ts**

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openDialog($event: any) {
     // open desired car component
  }

}
```

Look at official doc: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I am getting this **ERROR:**   `_co.openDialog is not a function`

Comment: let's try now please

Comment: Thanks a lot!! you have saved my day.